# Change associated Product Sku on change of configurable product attributes dropdown in detail page in Magento2

Tags: magento2, magento-2.2.5

I need dynamic Associated product sku change in product detail page on change of product super attributes dropdown or swatches.

Plugins available are not free it seems. can anyone help?

Comment: Hi. I think there are hidden field named "selected_configurable_option" on detail page where on click options simple product id updated. I think you can use it.

Comment: @Raj , Thanks for answering. I am not able to get event for that change as its hidden input.

Comment: Have u find hidden field or not?

Comment: Yes, it is there with required information. But I need some event so that I can get it whenever it is changing

Comment: In which file you want to use that value?

Comment: In modal quickview and product detail page

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/86963/discussion-between-raj-and-pallavi).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think there are hidden field named "selected_configurable_option" on detail page where on click options simple product id updated. I think you can use jquery onchange event for get that hidden field value and use it on your file. Thanks.